# Consume WCF Service and pass data into dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am really struggling with this.   I have created a WCF Service with BizTalk and I have followed instructions to create the Proxy class in VS 2010.  If everything is at the top level of the XML schema its fine but what I am struggling with is that I have XML Schema that has record elements at the top level.

Policy
   - ClientRecord - name, address, post code etc....

Policy
  - ProductRecord - ProdID, Desc, price etc...

The method exposed is Operation1 which effectively needs an XML object passed into it as a BizTalk Receive.

All the examples show creating an instance of the service and then you can strongly type it.  I can't work out how to create a new instance and then be able to strongly type into a dataset.

What I want to do is something like `policy.clientrecord.name = textbox1.text`.  At present all I get is the `policy.clientrecord.namecolumn` exposed which is readonly.

I am really confused and can't find examples out there that match although it must be done all the time.  I could lump everything into the root of the XML file but this makes it messy, unless you can create the schema another way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I now realise the error of my ways, I was calling it completely wrongly largely due to being a newbie.  I have been hunting and hunting for help and in the end it come from some very ground up basics (other examples had me going off in all directions).

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Client/

To get it working with my Biztalk WCF service which was a published orchestration I just added the proxy classes generated by SVCUTIL and renamed the file to app.config.

Comment: Congratulations. You've learned a valuable lesson - when you can't find examples, you have to learn the basics on your own - then build your own examples.